# Acting when button down and button up in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to detect when a button is pressed (down) but not released (up) in tcl/tk.

When you click a button, it's associated command is only executed after you let go and button goes back up.

> From tcl/tk documentation:
>   "*Command-Line Name: -command
>   Database Name: command
>   Database Class: Command
>   Specifies a Tcl command to associate with the button. This command is typically invoked when mouse button 1 is released over the button window.*"

Typically?

How does my command execute when a button is down?

Comment: `bind .b <ButtonPress-1> {puts Down}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-command` callback is effectively a high-level event that triggers in response to a particular event sequence. In terms of low-level events, you have to `<Enter>` the widget, `<ButtonPress-1>` (often shortened to `<Button-1>` or just `<1>`) over the button to start the click and then `<ButtonRelease-1>` over the button while not doing a `<Leave>` or `<B1-Leave>` in the intervening period (without an `<Enter>` or `<B1-Enter>` to reverse it). It's a little bit complicated!

But you can always add your own bindings.

```
bind .btn <ButtonPress-1> {puts "pressed the button"}
bind .btn <ButtonRelease-1> {puts "released the button"}
```

If you're doing anything complicated, be aware that a binding script that finishes with `break` will prevent any later bindings (e.g., the button class bindings) from firing. Buttons have class bindings for these events: `<ButtonRelease-1>`, `<Button-1>`, `<Leave>`, `<Enter>`, `<<Invoke>>` (this is a virtual event), and `<Key-space>`.

Comment: More than I need. Thank you! :)